# How to Generate Word Cloud with + Symbol

Tags: python, regex, word-cloud

I am trying to generate a word cloud where a word has a `+` symbol in it. I am aware that the `+` symbol has special meaning in RegEx, and I am also aware there is a `regexp` parameter in `WordCloud()`. However, I am not sure how to adjust this to allow for the `+` to show in the word cloud output?

Below is my current code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS

# Define a function to plot word cloud
def plot_cloud(wordcloud):
    # Set figure size
    plt.figure(figsize=(40, 30))
    # Display image
    plt.imshow(wordcloud) 
    # No axis details
    plt.axis("off");

file1 = open(r"word_cloud.txt")
text = file1.read()

wordcloud = WordCloud(width = 3000, height = 500, random_state=1, 
                          background_color='white', colormap='viridis', 
                          collocations=False, stopwords = STOPWORDS).generate(text)
plot_cloud(wordcloud)
```

Would appreciate any help on this.

**EDIT**

Editing as apparently my initial question is not clear.

Objective: Create a word cloud that contains the symbol `+`.

In the above code it is generating the word cloud but the word with a `+` symbol does not have it, i.e. the word C++ is coming up as just C. I have created a new set of `STOPWORDS` so this parameter is not the issue. I belive it has to do with the `regexp` parameter of `WordCloud()` function - but I am not sure as I don't know a whole lot about regular expressions.

To further elaborate, I have the below in the `word_cloud.txt` file:

```
VBA VBA VBA VBA VBA VBA VBA VBA VBA VBA VBA VBA VBA VBA VBA VBA VBA VBA VBA VBA VBA VBA VBA VBA 
Excel Excel Excel Excel Excel Excel Excel Excel Excel Excel Excel Excel Excel Excel Excel Excel 
C++ C++ C++ C++ C++ C++ C++ C++
```

But this is showing up as the below in the word cloud:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure `STOPWORDS` do not contain punctuation (and plus sign as well)?

Comment: @sophros yes, I have printed out `STOPWORDS` and it does not include the `+` symbol.

Comment: @sophros I have also created my own set of stop words and it does not include the `+` symbol. I believe it has something to do with the `regexp` parameter.

Comment: you are not using regexes in your snippet.

Comment: @sophros yes, that is my issue. I don't know what to set the `regexp` parameter to allow the processing of the `+` symbol

Comment: @sophros I have edited my original post, hopefully this is more clear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *assume* that by default `WordCloud` is using only words (e.g. regex similar to `r'\w'`).
In order to treat `+` sign as part of the word I suggest you go along these lines:

```
r'[a-zA-z\+]+'
```

This [should work](https://pythex.org/?regex=%5Ba-zA-z%5C%2B%5D%2B&test_string=VBA%20VBA%20VBA%20VBA%20VBA%20VBA%20VBA%20VBA%20VBA%20VBA%20VBA%20VBA%20VBA%20VBA%20VBA%20VBA%20VBA%20VBA%20VBA%20VBA%20VBA%20VBA%20VBA%20VBA%20%0AExcel%20Excel%20Excel%20Excel%20Excel%20Excel%20Excel%20Excel%20Excel%20Excel%20Excel%20Excel%20Excel%20Excel%20Excel%20Excel%20%0AC%2B%2B%20C%2B%2B%20C%2B%2B%20C%2B%2B%20C%2B%2B%20C%2B%2B%20C%2B%2B%20C%2B%2B&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0).

Comment: Amazing, thank you! And also thanks for the Pythex reference - super helpful.